# Cómo detectar una pagina 404 al usar file_get_contents

Tags: php, condiciones, else, error404

¿Cómo puedo detectar un 404 en una pagina con php ... es posible? ,si la página buscada (url) no se encuentra y me da un error 404...
este es el código que estoy usando :

```
<?php 
for($pagina=50;$pagina<60;$pagina++){ 

$data = file_get_contents("https://sitioweb.com/?p=".$pagina); 

 if ( preg_match('|<h2 style="text-align: center;">(.*?)</h2>|is' , $data , $cap ) ) 
{ 

    echo '<b>'.$cap[1] .'</b><br>'; 
} 
} 

?>
```

Mas o menos estoy buscando es asi :

if ( $data = 404 not found) {
echo pagina no existe }else {
seguir rastreando}

Comment: Probaste editando el .htaccess? Con esta linea cada vez que sale un error 404 redirecciona a otra pagina donde podes armar algo que diga La pagina no existe como los ejemplos que hay en muchas paginas cuando queres entrar a una pagina que no existe: ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404/  Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962787/rewrite-url-after-redirecting-404-error-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

A ver que te parece usando cURL:

```
<?php
// Crear un nuevo recurso cURL
$ch = curl_init();

// recorremos las paginas a revisar 
for ($pagina = 50; $pagina < 60; $pagina++) {

    $url = 'https://sitioweb.com/?p=' . $pagina;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    // ejecutamos la pagina actual
    curl_exec($ch);
    // leemos la info obtenida
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    /*
      // podemos ver el resto de datos
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($info);
      echo '</pre>';
     */

    // comparamos el código de error 
    if ($info['http_code'] == '404') {
        echo 'Falló: <b>' . $url . '</b><br>';
    }

    curl_close($ch);
}
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/es/ref.curl.php

http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-getinfo.php